# Laravel 5.3: How to save images - Is Intervention still available?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I began to use Laravel 5.3, wondering if `Intervention` is still compatible or not.

I followed [the documentation](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel), but I keep getting an error message, saying that

> Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found

I simply added `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class` into `$providers` and also added `'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class`
 into `$aliases`. Then, I began to see the error message.

When I was using Laravel 5.2, this didn't happen, as far as I remember.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run following command:

**Step 1**

```
$ composer require intervention/image
```

**Step 2**

In the `$providers` array add the service providers for this package.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

**Step 3**

Add the facade of this package to the $aliases array.

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

**Step 4**

```
$ php artisan config:clear
$ php artisan cache:clear
```

**Step 5**

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got `Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found ` even after I run it :(

Comment: Umm step 4 gives me 'Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found '